# How To Use Class As Property

Tags: c#

I tried using class as a property but I can't change it's sub properties in the "Properties Tab"

I want to make a property like the `Font` property 
in this picture

[image]

Comment: You'll have to provide a property editor for this.

Comment: do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: It's better if you include your image directly in your question.

Comment: @hatchet i couldn't it said i need 10 reputation points to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to decorate it with `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]` to get the sub-properties to show up in the editor.

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int One;
    public int Two;
    public int Three;
}

public class MyEditableClass : Control
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    public MyStruct MyProperty { get; set; } = new MyStruct();
}
```

The properties will now be expandable.

Comment: Should it not be `new MyStruct()` instead of `new MyProperty()` in the property initialisation?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it